Можно ли сделать подключение вне России к Российскому дедику Minecraft
Можно ли сделать подключение вне России к Российскому дедику Minecraft.
У меня дедик в россии свой, на винде. Можно ли сделать чтобы например украинцы могли зайти на мои сервера Minecraft? роутер Kinetic, dns от google(8.8.8.8)

Если один провайдер (страна) заблокирован у другого и наоборот, то поможет разве что VPN) вроде как, CloudFlare и подобные, проксируют, мб поможет)
